# Alternate node/add page

Tags: panels

I would like to create an alternate node/add page, which can be accessed by a url path, so that I can have an alternate add node page for users while admins can see a different add node page.

This are my current selection rules:

This panel will be selected if Current path is "test", and NOT (Logged in user has role "anonymous user").

I get a 404 error when I access "test". I've tried adding the Node being edited is type "Test". selection rule but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Nikit is on to something below, but there's some important part of the puzzle missing. "Selection rules" doesn't seem to relevant to your problem, you shouldn't need to be using them, or at least not the way you are trying to do it. I think you need to take a step back and look at some page manager tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, I will watch the tutorials by Johan Falk. In the meantime, would you please give me some hints on what you think I'm missing?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've confused the roles of pages and selection rules with each other. It appears like you expect selection rules to create new URLs.

Comment: Yes , I really didn't know about it, but I learnt from Nikit that I must create a page with page manager first. However I'm still facing problems as you can see from my reply to him.

Answer (score 0):

Due to talking from comments, there answer that help:

You can't alternate node/add/{node_type} via Test. 
You can **create alias Test for node/add/{node_type}** or you can write custom function, that call node/add/{node_type} form via drupal_get_form with some node preparements function. 
After this you can apply Panels and so on

First answer was incorrect:
Enable **Page manager** module (part of CTools), then goto admin/structure/pages and add 'Add custom page', set path to *test*, save it. Now you can use your Panels that fire for Test page.

Answer (score 0):

You could be more specific about what you meant by add node page. Did you mean node/add page? If thats the case, then I would suggest you use [Menu Item Visibility](https://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) to hide the default add node link and make it visible to only your admin role(s), then create a block containing the add node-type links (eg node/add/article etc) and descriptions the way you want other users to see it, place this block inside your panel page (/test), and create a menu item that links to /test, making this only visible to non-admin users.

Drawback for this is that each time you add a new content type for non-admin users, you have to manually add a link for it to this block

**Edit:** Alternatively, since you want to achieve this using rules, you can install the [Rules Bonus Pack](https://drupal.org/project/rb) module (You need Rules module for this), the sub-module you want to enable is the "Miscellaneous", then Create Event "Page variant is rendered" Condition "Logged in user has role (your role), Action "Page Redirect" here you add the page "test" without the quotes (dont add a leading slash as in /test). Then you can do whatever you want on that page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I've got that part generally covered by only including certain forms in that panel page and using Field Permissions. My problem is making the panel page (/test) work, and I haven't finished watching the tutorials yet.

Comment: i have edited the answer to suit your panel rules requirement

Comment: Hmm actually my problem is that I cannot get that "test" page to work. I can actually solve the redirection problem more easily with a url alias and selection rules now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! Though with a very simple and dirty solution.

1. I created a variant for my node add/edit page with the following selection rules:

   This panel will be selected if Node being edited is type "Test", and NOT (Logged in user has role "admin").
2. Then I made a URL alias for node/add/test for "test"

Thank you all for your time spent helping me. I thought of it while following your instructions.